# How to make Scanner return delimiters as tokens

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I am trying to use [`java.util.Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html) to tokenize an arithmetic expression, where the delimiters can either be:

- Whitespace (`\s+` or `\p{Space}+`), which should be discarded
- Punctation (`\p{Punct}`), which should be returned as tokens

### Example

Given this expression:

```
12 + (ab-bc*3)
```

I would like Scanner to return these tokens:

- `12`
- `+`
- `(`
- `ab`
- `-`
- `bc`
- `*`
- `3`
- `)`

### Code

So far, I have only been able to:

- Eat up all of the punctation characters (not what I wanted):

  - `new Scanner("12 + (ab-bc*3)").useDelimiter("\\p{Space}+|\\p{Punct}").tokens().collect(Collectors.toList())`
  - Result: `"12", "", "", "", "ab", "bc", "3"`
- Achieve partial success using [positive lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1547827/238421)

  - `new Scanner("12 + (ab-bc*3)").useDelimiter("\\p{Space}+|(?=\\p{Punct})").tokens().collect(Collectors.toList())`
  - Result: `"12", "+", "(ab", "-bc", "*3", ")"`

But now I am stuck.

Comment: You could match them all using `"\\p{Punct}|\\w+"` regex

Comment: Unfortunately, this regex ate all my tokens: `new Scanner("12 + (ab-bc*3)").useDelimiter("\\p{Punct}|\\w+").tokens()` returns only empty strings

Comment: I said *matching* them all, in Scanner, you *split* with the pattern. See [Java demo](https://ideone.com/ED5EY1).

Comment: I'd say you wouldn't get what you want because you're trying to only specify the kind of delimiter you want, but you never say what kind of token you want. As far as scanner is concerned, there are no delimiters in `"-bc"`, and I don't think there's any possible configuration to change that (technically, a delimiter in there is an "empty char", which isn't actually a thing). You need to say what kinds of tokens you want, by changing `.token()` to `.findAll` with proper regex, like what Wiktor suggested.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you're right, it worked! `Pattern.compile("\\p{Punct}|\\w+").matcher("12 + (ab-bc*3)").results().map(MatchResult::group).collect(Collectors.toList())` returns `"12", "+", "(", "ab", "-", "bc", "*", "3", ")"`

Comment: @DaniloPiazzalunga, you may want to save the pattern somewhere in real app, to not keep creating and parsing regex for the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *matching* approach allows you to use a much simpler regex here:

```
String text = "12 + (ab-bc*3)";
List<String> results = Pattern.compile("\\p{Punct}|\\w+").matcher(text)
    .results()
    .map(MatchResult::group)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(results); 
// => "12", "+", "(", "ab", "-", "bc", "*", "3", ")"
```

See [**Java demo**](https://ideone.com/gMvLLt).

The regex matches

- `\p{Punct}` - punctuation and symbol chars
- `|` - or
- `\w+` - 1+ letters, digits or `_` chars.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2wflDa/1) (converted to PCRE for the demo purpose).